# Growl notifications when a user logs in to Minecraft server?

Tags: notifications, console, growl

Would love to be able to get a Growl notification when a user logs in to my (locally hosted) Minecraft server.

I took a peek in the Console but it doesn't seem to record the logins, although my server GUI shows activity on the server including logins.

It runs within Java, so maybe that's the issue with it not showing up in the Console, although some of my actions do seem to get recorded, but those seem related to the main Minecraft app and not the server.

Even if I could find the logs, I am at a loss as to how one sets up a Growl notification, although I assume it has to do with growlNotify: http://growl.info/extras.php#growlnotify

Comment: I think this is more of a minecraft question than an OS X question. You are correct in using growlnotify but you need to be able to get information out of minecraft to use this.

Comment: Does the minecraft server produce a log file on disk any place? Is there a setting to override where/how that logging is done?

Comment: Lyken - I see this as more of a Mac/Growl question than specifically a Minecraft question, since it's more about using Growl for Mac events. It just happens to be related to Minecraft as well.

Comment: Ian C - as patrix mentioned below, there is a log file located here: /Users/George/Documents/MinecraftServerSettings/server/server.log

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The minecraft server writes a log file into the directory `minecraft_server.jar` is installed in. From there you can use something like

```
tail -f server.log | 
  while read m_date m_time m_type m_user m_ip m_action m_rest; do
    if [[ $m_action == logged ]]; then
      growlnotify -n Minecraft -m "$m_user logged in at $m_date $m_time" Minecraft;
    fi
  done
```

Starting this automatically together with your Minecraft server is possible but depends on the way you do start it.

To install this (without going too deep into Unix territory, ask an expert if it fails):

- open Terminal.app
- change to the directory where minecraft_server.jar is installed by typing `cd` followed by drag&dropping the folder with the server into the terminal window followed by return
- `nano mc2growl`
- write `#!/bin/bash` and press return (twice)
- paste the code from above
- press ^X and say Y at the prompt
- `chmod +x mc2growl`
- `./mc2growl &`

Comment: Patrix — thanks! How do I go about using the code you provided? I'm a bit of a dabbler when it comes to this stuff, but it's over my head a bit. Trying to learn.

Comment: Oh, and I am using OSX SMP SERVER GUI to launch the server: http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/23614-software-osx-smp-server-gui-v021-13-01/

Comment: Patrix — sorry I am not receiving email notifications for replies. However, I followed your instructions and it worked perfectly! Thanks so much. I have to say however that this is entirely beyond my experience. Again — thank you!

Comment: Seems this does not launch on reboot, and I am not sure which part of the process I need to do in Terminal to restart everything.

Answer (score 0):

(Full disclosure: This is my app.)

I've made an app for Mac and Windows that does this, even for vanilla servers and Minecraft Realms servers!

http://www.creeprapp.com